# What is the difference between Query build time Query execute time View render time in drupal veiws

Tags: views, debugging, performance

I'm using drupal views and set Live preview settings enabled.
I'm curious about the difference between three factors: *build time*, *execute time* and *render time*. Sometime when I change a filter or sort criteria one of them increases and another one decreases.

So which one should be lowest? Which one affects on page load speed? What is the difference between them?